# Changing image in picture box rapidly

Tags: c#, picturebox

I am trying to display 3 images in rapid succession, around 200ms per image. Here is the code right now i have:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
        {
            if ((_currentGridPos >= 0 && _currentGridPos < 2) || (_currentGridPos >= 3 && _currentGridPos < 5))
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Nyago\Images\g" + _currentGridPos + "_r" + i + ".JPG");
                pictureBox1.Refresh();
                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
        }
```

The problem I am having with this code is that the images aren't showing up in my picture box, there is just the pause then thats it. If someone could help me it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why would you use `Thread.Sleep` for this? What's wrong with a good old `Timer`?

Comment: I think you're changing the image in the UI thread.

Comment: Also, try to load images from the file only once, outside of the loop. It might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll suggest you to mark the method `async` and use `Task.Delay`

```
private async void DoSomething()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        if ((_currentGridPos >= 0 && _currentGridPos < 2) || (_currentGridPos >= 3 && _currentGridPos < 5))
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Nyago\Images\g" + _currentGridPos + "_r" + i + ".JPG");
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
            await Task.Delay(200);//<--Note Task.Delay don't block UI
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code keeps the UI thread busy and therefore blocks the UI (including updating its graphical state). Avoid using `Thread.Sleep(200);`; use a timer or async/await instead. That way, the UI thread is not blocked while waiting for the 200ms to pass.