# Switching images in picturebox

Tags: c#, image, winforms, linq, picturebox

In Windows Forms Application I have to display a few (or more) images in one picturebox - they need to change every 10 seconds (or similar).
I first retrieve images from a database and display them in a specific picturebox.
Every image has an unique ID and for only one image everything works fine.

I have SQL database (SQL Server 2014) and use LINQ.

```
public void displayAdds(ImageAd img, int imgid)
    {

         using (var dbContext = new LinqClassesDataContext())
        {

            var table = from t in dbContext.ImageAds
                        where t.Id == imgid
                        select t;

            img.image = table.Single().image;

            pictureBox1.Image = ByteArrayToImage(img.image.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

In the end the 'displaying' has to be in foreach loop, because I will have a list of ints (List), so I could display only images with selected IDs.

I tried using threads, or refreshing, and a simple loop like this didn't work:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
 {
    displayAdds(img, i);
   }
```

Here are other methods I tried and didn't work.

```
public void displayAd(ImageAd img)
    {
        int i = 1;

        using (var dbContext = new LinqClassesDataContext())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var table = from t in dbContext.ImageAds
                            where t.Id == i
                            select t;

                img.image = table.Single().image;

                pictureBox1.Image = ByteArrayToImage(img.image.ToArray());

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                i++;

                if (i >= 15)
                    i = 1;
            }

        }
    }


    public void displayList(ImageAd img)
    {
        using (var dbContext = new LinqClassesDataContext())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                var table = from t in dbContext.ImageAds
                            where t.Id == i
                            select t;

                img.image = table.Single().image;

               // pictureBox1.Image = ByteArrayToImage(img.image.ToArray());

                PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
                //254,15
                pb.Location = new Point(254, 15);
                pb.Size = new Size(310, 367);
               // pb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
                pb.Image = ByteArrayToImage(img.image.ToArray());
                pb.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
                this.Controls.Add(pb);
                pb.BringToFront();

                Thread.Sleep(1000);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Let me guess, your application freezes? You can't just use Thread.Sleep like this. Try to get familiar with a Timer, with its Tick event first.

Comment: Actually it throws exception when it should pass to the form with images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way that so far works fine.
It turned out it was already on StackOverflow and unfortunately I hadn't found it earlier: [Changing image in picture box rapidly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489955/changing-image-in-picture-box-rapidly)

and I used it like this:

```
     var table = from t in dbContext.ImageAds where t.Id == i select t;
                    img.image = table.Single().image;

                    pictureBox1.Image = ByteArrayToImage(img.image.ToArray());
                    pictureBox1.Refresh();
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = Enumerable.Range(1,15).ToArray();

//First get all image from db
var images = from t in dbContext.ImageAds
    where array.Contains(t.Id)
    select t.image;

//create thread for delay to prevent freezing screen
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        foreach (var img in array)
        {
            // call method in ui thread
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate //this: form control
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = ByteArrayToImage(img.ToArray());
            });
            Thread.Sleep(1000);                        
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It almost helped, I adjusted the code and I have smth like null reference exception. Could you help me find the problem?Here's the code: http://paste.ofcode.org/YGvBXhQTrXhWJQgzNgdJjF

Comment: @leapp this answer is approach not right code, so you must adopt this code with your code and resolve problems that might be occurred in your try.

Comment: @leapp However which line exception occurred?

Comment: this one  pictureBox1.Image = ByteArrayToImage(imga.image.ToArray());

Comment: so I shouldn't put your code in one method? could you guide me how should do it? I really need some tips because I know I won't figure it out all by my own (I've already tried & I'm kinda new in threads and querying db in c#)